# How to troubleshoot network delay

Tags: ros, kinect, network, bandwidth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My robot sends kinect XYZ and RGB data to PC through wifi.
The amount of data for each frame is about 700KB, but I can only send 3 frames every second. If I send more frame , the network will be delay heavily.
Is this normal?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65839/how-to-troubleshoot-network-delay/) by [Robin Hu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3839/robin-hu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2013-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming wlan standard 802.11b, the maximal bandwith is 11 MBit/s = 1,375 MByte/s. If one kinect frame amounts to 700kBytes, 2 fps would be the upper max. Using wlan standard 802.11g, 22 MBit/s = 2,75 MByte/s = 4fps would be realistic. So I would say that your 3 fps seem to be normal, yes.

depending on your scenario, you could try to separate data acquisition and processing: send only the raw data (rgb, depth map) over the network and assemble the full XYZRGB point cloud at the receivers end.

---

Originally posted by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) with karma: 990 on 2013-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robin Hu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3839/robin-hu/) on 2013-06-25**:
Think you very much , I will try it!